# Android RecyclerView last item remove (runtime) error

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` with custom list item and with `CardView` item, in two different `Activities`. Now i am getting error when i remove last remained item from list, i did not change any code related to those `acitivities` or `adapter` or `RecyclerView`.

Error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.widget.OrientationHelper$2.getDecoratedStart(OrientationHelper.java:316)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findOneVisibleChild(LinearLayoutManager.java:1633)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleChildClosestToStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:1453)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.computeScrollOffset(LinearLayoutManager.java:997)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.computeVerticalScrollOffset(LinearLayoutManager.java:969)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset(RecyclerView.java:1175)
        at android.view.View.canScrollVertically(View.java:12745)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS.canScrollVertically(ViewCompatICS.java:35)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.canScrollVertically(ViewCompat.java:940)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(ViewCompat.java:1237)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerView.java:6594)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerView.java:6573)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(LinearLayoutManager.java:204)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:66)
        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:228)
        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:56)
        at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5292)
        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5160)
        at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:20325)
        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:117)
        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:210)
        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:358)
        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:255)
        at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:82)
        at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7653)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.runOrPost(ViewRootImpl.java:7679)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.postSendWindowContentChangedCallback(ViewRootImpl.java:6871)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewRootImpl.java:6944)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2746)
        at android.view.View.notifySubtreeAccessibi
```

There is nothing related shown to my code here. I am using `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.+'
compile 'net.i2p.android.ext:floatingactionbutton:1.8.0'
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.4.7'}
```

Any idea what might be problem?

Comment: I realized that error occures when i use v7:22 libraries, it was used by `'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.4.7'` library so it overwrites my library v7:21 and uses v7:22.

Comment: I've tested on a handful of different devices, and my personal HTC One M8 (with the latest HTC-official 5.0.1 Android level) is the only one that has this problem. It's 100% reproducible but has occurred on NO other devices running the very same version of Android.

Comment: @CharlesMadere it happens on my 4.4.2 samsung s5, probably it depends on how custom RecyclerView adapter is implemented, i am not sure.

Comment: There's an issue open in the Android bug tracker - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162753

Comment: Can anyone verify if this problem has been fixed in the latest support library? (version `22.1.1`)

Comment: @CharlesMadere I'm still seeing this issue in a project using 22.1.1.

Comment: Was getting this error with 22.0.0, though 22.2.0 seems to have fixed it

Comment: I'm still seeing this error with recyclerview-v7:25.3.1

Answer (score 7):

I made a workaround for this by creating a child class for [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html). It's an unfortunate solution but at least it'll work until the support library fixes this problem...

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class LinearLayoutManagerWrapper extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private static final String TAG = "LinearLayoutManagerWrapper";
    public LinearLayoutManagerWrapper(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(final AccessibilityEvent event) {
        try {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
        } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException in onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(" + event +
                    ')', e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(final RecyclerView.Recycler recycler,
            final RecyclerView.State state, final AccessibilityEvent event) {
        try {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(recycler, state, event);
        } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException in onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(" + recycler +
                    ", " + state + ", " + event + ')', e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code fixed the problem for me, thanks. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162753

Answer (score 1):

Error occured because one of libraries use `v7:22` library of `appcompat` and `recyclerview`. I did overwrite dependency to use v7:21 by writing:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'){force=true}
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'){force=true}
```

I am not still sure why v7:22 latest library gives error on recycler view last item delete.

Comment: 22.0.1 is the current latest. Why are you forcing? Are you bringing them in as jars?

Comment: @JaredBurrows nope, `RecyclerView` gives runtime error when deleting last item if i use `22`, i dont know why

Comment: Why are you forcing? You can just specify 21.

Comment: @JaredBurrows even if i specify, one of my libraries use v22 and it overwrites what i specified

Comment: Does doing this give you the `This support library should not use a lower version (21) than the targetSdkVersion (22)` warning / error? I feel like I'd rather not make this change, especially if libraries prefer other versions. I too use Material Dialogs.